# React: Scale instead of resize

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code to resize an element in React.
The element is resized using `setEffect` while providing dynamic `width` and `height`.

**I want to scale the element on height change instead of resizing it so when the windows height is changed, the element is scaled down instead of resized. How to do so ? Keeping the same ratio.**

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-hermann-vmweu?file=/src/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function MyComponent() {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = React.useState({
    height: window.innerHeight,
    width: window.innerWidth
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const debouncedHandleResize = debounce(function handleResize() {
      setDimensions({
        height: window.innerHeight,
        width: window.innerWidth
      });
    }, 10);

    window.addEventListener("resize", debouncedHandleResize);

    return (_) => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", debouncedHandleResize);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div>
      Rendered at {dimensions.width} x {dimensions.height}
      <br />
      <img
        style={{ width: dimensions.width, height: dimensions.height }}
        src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/digital-device-mockup_53876-89354.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

function debounce(fn, ms) {
  let timer;
  return (_) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout((_) => {
      timer = null;
      fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }, ms);
  };
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, rootElement);
```

Edit : I found an alternative https://react-grid-layout.github.io/react-resizable/examples/1.html but I don't know how to link the box to the windows size instead of manual size.

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding what you are looking for. Is changing in your img tag to "style={{ maxWidth: dimensions.width, maxHeight: dimensions.height }}" doing it for you?

Comment: @Viktor W Yes ? This is so close to what I want to do. It's actually working when scaling the window. But when changing the window size further, the image width become very ugly WHEN setting a fixed `width`. What I want is to be able to scale the element when changing the size of the window, instead of changing his whole size. Your solution DOES scale it, but the width become buggy. You can try it directly in the code.

Comment: Okay how about just "style={{ width: dimensions.width }}". Or as Cody E pointed out, just "style={{ width: "100vw" }}"

Comment: @Viktor W It's still have that ugly width.

Comment: @ViktorW Example to give you and idea about the type of scale i have in mind  https://codepen.io/cRckls/pen/mcGCL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve the aspect ratio, check the original images aspect ratio using `img.naturalWidth` and `img.naturalHeight`.

```
    const [dimensions, setDimensions] = React.useState({
        height: window.innerHeight,
        width: window.innerWidth
    });
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const debouncedHandleResize = debounce(function handleResize() {
            setDimensions({
                height: window.innerHeight,
                width: window.innerWidth
            });
        }, 10);

        window.addEventListener("resize", debouncedHandleResize);

        return (_) => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", debouncedHandleResize);
        };
    });

    const imgRef = React.useRef()
    if (imgRef.current) {
        const ratio = imgRef.current.naturalWidth / imgRef.current.naturalHeight;
        if (dimensions.width / dimensions.height > ratio) {
            var imageDimensions = {
                width: dimensions.height,
                height: dimensions.height
            };
        } else {
            var imageDimensions = {
                width: dimensions.width,
                height: dimensions.width
            };
        }
    } else {
        var imageDimensions = {};
    }

    return (
    <div>
      Rendered at {dimensions.width} x {dimensions.height}
      <br />
      <img
        ref={imgRef}
        style={{ width: imageDimensions.width, height: imageDimensions.height }}
        src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/digital-device-mockup_53876-89354.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg"
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-antonelli-ii922?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind! Thank you very much. Although you solved the problem, I'm still a beginner in React and your code is a little complex for me to understand so I will give it some time. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Unless I'm missing something, this is just a css antipattern.

If you want an element to be a certain ratio of the screen width, use `vh` `vw`

If you want an element to be a certain ratio of the parent element, use `%`

If you want an element to scale with the font, use `rem` or `em`

I think the problems you are having is that you are setting it to px (and setting it in the state, which isn't great either for the record, but you are debouncing which helps)

Comment: Thank for the suggestions. What I want is, when the user modify the windows size, the element (in this case image) should be scaled down to fit the window. Maybe the image will scale down with what you suggested, but a complete `div` with a lot of elements inside will not.

Comment: Consider implementing a `mobile` mode? When you are under a certain scale, you change the classes to match a mobile viewport, this is a pretty common pattern.

Comment: Well if you are talking about using media queries, when modify the height of the window, the element will not scale down in this case. It will scale only on width change.